# Pyspark parse custom date format

Tags: apache-spark, datetime, pyspark

I face this challenge: I have a complex date format that comes as a string. So I use the [unix_timestamp](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp) function to parse it.

However I can not find the proper pattern to use. I do not know the proper abbreviations for timezone, day of week and month and I have not found a single link to clarify on them.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp

d =  spark.createDataFrame([(1,"Mon Jan 14 11:43:20 EET 2019"),\
                          (2,"Wed Jun 27 16:26:46 EEST 2018")],\
                          ["id","time_str"]) 

pattern = "aaa bbb dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy" 
d= d.withColumn("timestampCol", unix_timestamp(d["time_str"], pattern).cast("timestamp"))

d.show()
>>>
+---+------------------------------+------------+
|id |time_str                      |timestampCol|
+---+------------------------------+------------+
|1  |Mon Jan 14 11:43:20 EET 2019  |null        |
|2  |Wed Jun 27 16:26:46 EEST 2018 |null        |
+---+------------------------------+------------+
```

Does somenone know how to correctly convert this string to timestamps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the following code:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
d =  spark.createDataFrame([(1,"Mon Jan 14 11:43:20 EET 2019"),\
                      (2,"Wed Jun 27 16:26:46 EEST 2018")],\
                      ["id","time_str"]) 

pattern = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"
d.withColumn("timestamp", unix_timestamp(col("time_str"), pattern).cast("timestamp")).show(truncate=False)
```

It produces the output below. For further documentation you could refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html which I used to lookup the `EEE` and `MMM` which is required as you have 3 characters per weekday and Month respectively.

```python
+---+-----------------------------+-------------------+
|id |time_str                     |timestamp          |
+---+-----------------------------+-------------------+
|1  |Mon Jan 14 11:43:20 EET 2019 |2019-01-14 09:43:20|
|2  |Wed Jun 27 16:26:46 EEST 2018|2018-06-27 13:26:46|
+---+-----------------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: `IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character: E`. 

Seems not supported anymore: ```Symbols of ‘E’, ‘F’, ‘q’ and ‘Q’ can only be used for datetime formatting, e.g. date_format. They are not allowed used for datetime parsing, e.g. to_timestamp.```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html

Comment: What's the alternative for parsing dates with 'E'?